# Get marked range from NSTextInputContext

Tags: objective-c

I was trying to clean up deprecation warnings of a certain project and the snippet of code looked like:

```
NSInputManager* im = [NSInputManager currentInputManager];
if (im && [im markedRange].length > 0) return NO;
```

I got this far:

```
NSTextInputContext* im = [NSTextInputContext currentInputContext];
if (im && [im /* What goes here? */].length > 0) return NO;
```

I am trying to get the marked range of the `NSTextInputContext`. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
NSTextInputContext* context = [NSTextInputContext currentInputContext];
id<NSTextInputClient> client = context.client;
if (client && client.markedRange.length > 0) return NO;
```

The client is usually the text view with the focus, so the first responder of the key window. So, you can maybe bypass looking it up this way and just go straight to the text view.